# is it possible in IntelliJ to filter out stack in thread view by custom pattern

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

I'd like to filter out some entries from Threads View in IntelliJ by custom regexp pattern in order to hide not relevant entries. I'm aware of "Hide Frames from libraries" filter but it is not sufficient.

I tried to add pattern in Settings > Build ... > Debugger > Stepping but it didn't helped.

I will appreciate any hint.

[image]

Comment: Please vote for this request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191180

Comment: To make specific frames more distinguishable you can define custom scope for them, [associate them with color](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#predefined-scopes-list) Then frames view will also be colored accordingly.